# Why the bottom spacing is not working in small screens in angular application after deployment

Tags: angular, cross-browser, web-deployment, responsiveness, android-bottomnav

I have deployed my angular application successfully. But the problem is it is working fine for all devices except mobile.

When it comes to mobile devices the bottom spacing is not applied for chrome, firefox, or edge. And works fine in the same mobile devices 'Operamini' browser.

But also the important thing is it works fine for some mobiles in all browsers.

I don't know how to fix this issue. So kindly help me fix this problem.

```
The deployed application in chrome - mobile device ( mobile -device ) :
```

[image]

```
The same website in operaminini browser in same device ( below image ):
```

[image]

I want to fix it atleasr for chrome.Kindly help me.

*NOTE : This is looking correct in developer-tools*

Comment: Can you share your html and css(styles)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using the ngx-admin theme in my Angular application .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @media screens :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .mob-img {
        max-width: initial; 
        height: 230px;
        max-height: 384px;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I am using the ngx-admin template for my application, this issue comes for the whole application not for one page. Also sometimes, when i reload the application, this padding works as expected.